# NSPredicate format dynamically use property name

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I use this predicate for fetching objects from CoreData:

```
NSPredicate.init(format: "id in %@", ids)
```

So, my class has property called "id".

Is it possible to use the dynamic name of the property instead of hardcoding "id"?

The problem, at least for me, is that in case I change my property's name, I would need to change all predicates where it is used.

Instead I would want to use something like

```
NSPredicate.init(format: "%@ in %@", #keyPath(MyClass.id), ids)
```

This gives me a Predicate `"id" in <listOfIDs>`, while to make it works it requires `id in <listOfIDs>`

I understand this is very strange 'problem', but I really like to not use any of hardcoded properties' names in cases like this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you just need to use `"%K"` instead of `"%@"`.

```
NSPredicate.init(format: "%K in %@", #keyPath(MyClass.id), ids)
```